# Failed to implement treeview with a click handler in Angular

Tags: angular, treeview

I am trying to follow [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) and I copy-pasted the code into my own template and it throws me out these errors:
`Identifier 'dataSource' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member`

````
Identifier 'treeControl' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member```
````

```
Identifier 'hasChild' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member
```

```
Identifier 'treeControl' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member
```

I also need to a (click)="functionhere()" event handler to the leaflets in the treeview. What I need to do exactly is build an interface, which shows the group members in the treeview and when you click on a group member you can edit their details, but a simple click handler is good enough for starters. My code is the following:

treeview-tab.component.html:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.item}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.item}}
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="node.isLoading"
                      mode="indeterminate"
                      class="example-tree-progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

My .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CollectionViewer, SelectionChange} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {FlatTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, merge, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
 /** Flat node with expandable and level information */
export class DynamicFlatNode {
  constructor(public item: string, public level = 1, public expandable = false,
              public isLoading = false) {}
}

/**
 * Database for dynamic data. When expanding a node in the tree, the data source will need to fetch
 * the descendants data from the database.
 */
export class DynamicDatabase {
  dataMap = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['Fruits', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']],
    ['Vegetables', ['Tomato', 'Potato', 'Onion']],
    ['Apple', ['Fuji', 'Macintosh']],
    ['Onion', ['Yellow', 'White', 'Purple']]
  ]);

  rootLevelNodes: string[] = ['Fruits', 'Vegetables'];

  /** Initial data from database */
  initialData(): DynamicFlatNode[] {
    return this.rootLevelNodes.map(name => new DynamicFlatNode(name, 0, true));
  }

  getChildren(node: string): string[] | undefined {
    return this.dataMap.get(node);
  }

  isExpandable(node: string): boolean {
    return this.dataMap.has(node);
  }
}
/**
 * File database, it can build a tree structured Json object from string.
 * Each node in Json object represents a file or a directory. For a file, it has filename and type.
 * For a directory, it has filename and children (a list of files or directories).
 * The input will be a json object string, and the output is a list of `FileNode` with nested
 * structure.
 */
@Injectable()
export class DynamicDataSource {

  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<DynamicFlatNode[]>([]);

  get data(): DynamicFlatNode[] { return this.dataChange.value; }
  set data(value: DynamicFlatNode[]) {
    this._treeControl.dataNodes = value;
    this.dataChange.next(value);
  }

  constructor(private _treeControl: FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>,
              private _database: DynamicDatabase) {}

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<DynamicFlatNode[]> {
    this._treeControl.expansionModel.changed.subscribe(change => {
      if ((change as SelectionChange<DynamicFlatNode>).added ||
        (change as SelectionChange<DynamicFlatNode>).removed) {
        this.handleTreeControl(change as SelectionChange<DynamicFlatNode>);
      }
    });

    return merge(collectionViewer.viewChange, this.dataChange).pipe(map(() => this.data));
  }

  /** Handle expand/collapse behaviors */
  handleTreeControl(change: SelectionChange<DynamicFlatNode>) {
    if (change.added) {
      change.added.forEach(node => this.toggleNode(node, true));
    }
    if (change.removed) {
      change.removed.slice().reverse().forEach(node => this.toggleNode(node, false));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Toggle the node, remove from display list
   */
  toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean) {
    const children = this._database.getChildren(node.item);
    const index = this.data.indexOf(node);
    if (!children || index < 0) { // If no children, or cannot find the node, no op
      return;
    }

    node.isLoading = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (expand) {
        const nodes = children.map(name =>
          new DynamicFlatNode(name, node.level + 1, this._database.isExpandable(name)));
        this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...nodes);
      } else {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = index + 1; i < this.data.length
          && this.data[i].level > node.level; i++, count++) {}
        this.data.splice(index + 1, count);
      }

      // notify the change
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
      node.isLoading = false;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Tree with dynamic data
 */

export class TreeDynamicExample {
  constructor(database: DynamicDatabase) {
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new DynamicDataSource(this.treeControl, database);

    this.dataSource.data = database.initialData();
  }

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>;

  dataSource: DynamicDataSource;

  getLevel = (node: DynamicFlatNode) => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: DynamicFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: DynamicFlatNode) => _nodeData.expandable;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-treeview-tab',
  templateUrl: './treeview-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./treeview-tab.component.scss']
})
export class TreeviewTabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CarinaeComponent } from './carinae.component';
import { CarinaeRouting, CarinaeRoutingComponents } from './carinae.routing';

import { ListContentComponent } from './list-content/list-content.component';
import { TreeviewTabComponent } from './treeview-tab/treeview-tab.component';
import { AppSettingsComponent } from './app-settings/app-settings.component';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';
// Mat tree view begin
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatTreeModule,
} from '@angular/material';
// Mat Tree view end



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        CarinaeRoutingComponents,
        CarinaeComponent,
        ListContentComponent,
        TreeviewTabComponent,
        AppSettingsComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    CarinaeRouting,
    CommonModule,
    TreeModule.forRoot(),
    A11yModule, // TREEVIEW
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule, // TREEVIEW
  ],
  exports: [  // TREEVIEW
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,    // TREEVIEW
  ]
})
export class CarinaeModule { }
```

Comment: Show your module .ts file?

Comment: @Sela updated the question